# Authenticating against Office 365 SharePoint Online from an asp.net page in Azure

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, asp

I would like to authenticate against my SharePoint Online from my asp.net webpage in Azure.
What are the steps to get this started? Will this be via the client model?

Has anyone done this successfully?

Thanks in Advance